# We have data in Hive Tables on Hadoop . What are the different ways our downstream applications can receive this data?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Trying to find the integration points with Hive from architecture standpoint.
One of the option is Kafka. Any other options?

Reading various articles to find this out.

Comment: No, Kafka is not an option. Hive can query Kafka topics, not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

Most common are ODBC/JDBC connectors

Examples:
https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/jdbc/2-6-21.html
https://www.magnitude.com/drivers/hive-odbc-jdbc

There are many storage handlers supported by hive as well.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/JDBC+Storage+Handler
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration

Comment: Storage Handlers are only for reading external stores from Hive. That's not what the question was asking

Comment: by using storage handler you can push data from hive managed tables to external target referred by storage handler.

Comment: That depends on the handler, though. With the JDBC one, for example, writes are not supported according to the linked docs.

Comment: yes, some handlers support writes some don't